# Get checked status of radio buttons in a Data Repeater

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datarepeater

I have a Data Repeater in a Windows Form, within the data repeater I have a label and either a radio button or combo box, the amount of radio buttons and the text for them is brought in from my database as is the label and combo box.

The label is a question and the radio buttons or combo box allows the user to answer the question.

What I want to do is get the checked status of the radio buttons so I can then reveal the next question if it is needed. e.g. only show question 2 if question 1 is answered No.

Answer (score 0):

```
'0 = Index in Repeater.
Dim bolChecked As Boolean = CType(rptYourRepeater.Items(0).FindControl("IdOfRadioButton"), RadioButton).Checked
```

Comment: I get an error that says "'Items' is not a member of 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeater'"

Comment: I got some of it working, when you click a button it displays a message box with true or false if it is checked or not. `Dim bolChecked As Boolean = CType(rptYourRepeater.CurrentItem.Controls("IdOfRadioButton"), RadioButton).Checked
        MsgBox(bolChecked)`

Comment: My apologies for mixing up the DataRepeater and Repeater Controls and am glad you got it working.

Comment: Do you know how I would make this run when the checkbox is changed? I have tried CurrentItemIndexChanged but that only works once I click in another row in the DataRepeater.

Comment: Check out this link for a list of Events that may help you.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx